# Tree traversing

Tags: code-golf, binary-tree

Have you heard about trees?

When performing DFS on a binary tree, you can traverse it in 3 possible orders.

- Root, left node, right node (Pre-order)
- Left node, Root, right node (In-order)
- Left node, right node, root (Post-order)

Check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) to know [more](http://i1216.photobucket.com/albums/dd373/ncanales0822/28853015.jpg).

For this challenge, you have to provide a program that, given **the pre and in order traverses** of a tree returns the **original tree**.

Example 1:

**Inputs**
Preorder:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

In order:

```
[2 1 4 3 6 5 7]
```

Returns:

```
[1 [2 3 [4 5 [6 7]]]]
```

NOTES:

**Result notation**

```
[a [b c]]
```

Node `a` is the parent of nodes `b` and `c`. However in this one

```
[a [b [c]]]
```

Node `a` is the parent of node `b`, but it's `b` in this case the parent of `c`.

**More considerations**

- The tree might not be balanced.
- For every 2 traverses, the original tree is unique.
- Submissions can be programs and functions.
- The input format has to be a sequence of numbers representing the order in which the nodes are visited.
- The output format must be exactly as specified above.
- Shortest code in bytes wins.

Good luck

Comment: Are the elements guaranteed to be distinct?

Comment: So in the result, if there's only a single child, it's not defined whether the child is the left or the right?

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 114 bytes

```
[a]#_=show a
(a:b)#c|(d,_:e)<-span(/=a)c,(f,g)<-splitAt(length d)b=[a]#c++" ["++f#d++' ':g#e++"]"
a?b='[':a#b++"]"
```

Example run:

```
*Main> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]?[2,1,4,3,6,5,7]
"[1 [2 3 [4 5 [6 7]]]]"
```